# Showing evidence for informal savings

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

in our country people save money in informal, interest-free savings circles called ballot committees. these are run by housewives, students, office workers, shopkeepers, even high-society ladies. Each member of a group of trusted friends or relatives contributes the same sum daily or monthly to a pool for a predetermined length of time, usually one year. Through a ballot, each participant is allotted a number indicating his or her turn. Every month, one participant gets the pool total. Everyone on the committee keeps contributing until each member gets a pot of cash.

If I have been saving money using such means how can i show its evidence....each month a specific amount has been withdrawn from my account and after 6 months has been transferred in the form of a huge amount....how can i show the evidence of this huge amount coming from the commitee?

Comment: If the type of savings circle you describe is common in your country, it won’t be the first time the decision-makers will have come across it. If there is no ‘paper’ evidence, probably the best you can do is explain the system in your cover letter, pointing out the regular withdrawals (which will presumably tie up with what you received). But there’s no guarantee this will give you the outcome you hope for (a visa).